# SQL Server Script to List mdf and ldf files on the same drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a script to list all databases with data and transaction files are on the same drive. I'm not sure if I've done the join or the group by wrong, but it's listing all database files still. The SUBSTRING line pulls the drive letter out fine, I just need it to compare within each d.name group rather than against all other databases:

```
select 
    d.name, m.name, m.physical_name
from 
    sys.master_files m 
inner join 
    sys.databases d on (m.database_id = d.database_id) 
where
    d.name = d.name and
    substring(m.physical_name, 1, 1) = substring(m.physical_name, 1, 1) 
group by
    d.name, m.name, m.physical_name
order by 
    1
    --, 2
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping, you can do a double join, once for the log files and another for the data ones. Then, just check whether the first letter is the same:

```
select 
    DatabaseName = d.name,
    LogFileName = L.name,
    DataFileName = R.name,
    L.physical_name,
    R.physical_name
FROM
    sys.databases AS D
    INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS L ON 
        D.database_id = L.database_id AND
        L.type_desc = 'LOG'
    INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS R ON
        D.database_id = R.database_id AND
        R.type_desc = 'ROWS'
WHERE
    LEFT(L.physical_name, 1) = LEFT(R.physical_name, 1)
ORDER BY
    D.name
```

This will list the same database multiple times, depending on how many data files Vs. log files you have on the same drive. You can use `DISTINCT` and remove the file's columns from the `SELECT` if you just want it listed once.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirement is that you want to list databases whose data (MDF) and log (LDF) files are located *on different physical drives*.

In order to achieve that, you could try something like:

```
SELECT  d.name AS DatabaseName,
        mfr.name AS MdfFilename,
        mfr.physical_name AS MdfName,
        mfl.name AS LdfFilename,
        mfl.physical_name AS LdfName
  FROM  sys.master_files mfr
    INNER JOIN sys.master_files mfl ON mfl.database_id = mfr.database_id AND mfl.type_desc = 'LOG'
    INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mfr.database_id
  WHERE mfr.type_desc = 'ROWS' AND
        SUBSTRING(mfr.physical_name, 0, 1) <> SUBSTRING(mfl.physical_name, 0, 1)
```

This gets a list of all physical data and log files and then shows only those where the first character of the `physical_name` column are different.  The assumption being that this will indicate that the drive they are located on is different.

Note that you may not always have a single instance of each physical file.  For example, `tempdb` may typically have several separate data files, which would return several rows.  You may need to consider how to cater for this circumstance.

If you instead want ONLY instances where the files are physically located *on the same drive*, just tweak the `WHERE` clause to:

```
SUBSTRING(mfr.physical_name, 0, 1) = SUBSTRING(mfl.physical_name, 0, 1)
```

This changes the `<>` operator to `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry if it's not clear, I'm looking for any databases where their mdf & ldf are on the same drive. So if testdb1 has F:\Dir\data.mdf and F:\Dir\data.ldf then that's the ones I'd like to flag up. Cheers

Comment: @DavidHorgan See my most recent edit where I already added the extra code for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using DENSE_RANK() and a LEFT()

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT      database_id,
                        physical_name,
                        type_desc,
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY database_id ORDER BY LEFT(physical_name,1)) AS Rnk
            FROM        sys.master_files
        ) a
WHERE   Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this?

```
 select d.name, m.name,m.physical_name
 from sys.master_files m 
    inner join sys.databases d 
  on (m.database_id = d.database_id) 
  WHERE m.name = d.name
```